# In what sense is the sphere the limit of convex polyhedra?

Tags: geometry, spheres, polyhedra, combinatorial-geometry

It seems intuitively clear that the sphere can be approximated (both in surface area, but also in a more geometric sense) by certain classes of polyhedra. Do there exist any good formalizations of this notion? Is there a simple sequence of polyhedra which "converge" to the sphere? Does anyone know of a good reference on this subject?

Comment: For a simple sequence, make an evenly spaced latitude and longitude grid with $n-1$ parallels and $n$ meridians. Then use the points of the grid together with the poles as the vertices of a polyhedron with $n^2$ faces.

Comment: I suppose this would converge in $\sup_{x \in S^2} \inf_{y \in P_n} |x - y|$? Is there a name for this distance? Is this the "right"/"best" notion of convergence of geometric shapes, usually?

Comment: Some posts on this site mentioning the Schwarz lantern might be relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Schwarz+lantern

Comment: If I replace the pair (sphere, polyhedron) with (circle, polygon) then do you already have an answer in mind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A geodesic polyhedron is a candidate. Mathematica has a built-in function
`GeodesicPolyhedron[n]`. Here is $n=12$:

[image]

Comment: That's the first thing I thought of.  Maybe there's a generalization, which says: Take $n$ points all at unit distance from the origin, and let $P$ be their convex hull; as $n$ increases the convex hull approximates a sphere.  I'm not aware of any theorems about that but there must be some.

Comment: What's that pictured on the cover of _Discrete and Computational Geometry_?  Is it relevant here?

Comment: @MJD: The cover of my textbook is the convex hull of random points on a sphere. So accords with your idea.